# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'currentTime')

Tags: reactjs, audio, audio-player, current-time, react-library

i wanna leave page
but when i do it throws this error
however everything works correctly!

here is my code:

```
const repeat = useCallback(() => {
  const time = audioRef.current.currentTime;
  setTimeProgress(time);
  progressRef.current.value = (time / duration) * 100;

  playAnimationRef.current = requestAnimationFrame(repeat);
```

}, [audioRef, progressRef, duration]);

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]; without a [mre] this is unanswerable.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.